# L'inversion et l'accord du participe passé

Tags: accord, participe-passé, figure-de-style, inversion

Nous avons appris à l'école que le participe passé s'accorde avec *que*, qui remplace le complément direct dans une proposition relative (subordonnée relative), puisque ce dernier est avant le verbe.

Si on fait une inversion (en poésie, dans les fables ou seulement pour parler d'une manière spéciale) sans utiliser le pronom relatif, faut-il quand même faire cet accord, considérant qu'on n'utilise juste pas *que* ?

Voici des exemples:

1. Les pommes, j'ai mangées.

ou

2. Les pommes, j'ai mangé.

   ---

Simplification: Je me demandais si la règle s'applique même si on utilise le complément direct (dans une inversion, évidemment) à la place d'un pronom de remplacement (que, le, la, les, etc.).

Modif.: Ça prenait une virgule.

Comment: Où est le sujet par rapport au verbe avec ou sans la queue des pommes ? L'un et l'autre se dit ou se disent ? Quel bachelier nouvellement titré est capable de relever le défi ? 
En fait tout dépend de l'intention :

> [avec] les pommes, j'ai mangé (je n'ai plus faim)

>  les pommes je [les] ai mangées . Il faudrait vraiment un exemple poétique valable

Comment: C'est l'inversion de la phrase de base *J'ai mangé les pommes*.

Comment: Pour ceux qui veulent approfondir leurs recherches, ce type d'inversion est une figure de style nommée « hyperbate ». Puisse cela vous guider dans votre quête.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Concernant la construction

Point préliminaire : lorsque le complément est déplacé en début de phrase, il est suivi d'une virgule. La construction serait donc la suivante :

> Les pommes, j'ai mangé.

Sur les forums de *leconjugueur*, on relève que ce type de construction relève d'une figure de style appelée [hyperbate](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbate). Le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperbate) en donne de nombreux exemples, tous tirés des dialogues de Yoda dans *Star Wars*.

Au niveau grammatical, Danielle Leeman le définit comme une topicalisation, ou « le déplacement frontal d'un complément régi (par le verbe) sans reprise pronominale ».

#### À propos de l'accord

sur ce point, Danielle Leeman relève que, bien que ce groupe soit complément régi par le verbe, l'accord ne se fait pas dans ce cas particulier, détail qu'elle attribue à un possible « illogisme dans l'orthographe du français ».

[PERCE-NEIGE](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7373/perce-neige) présente [les choses de façon intéressante](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14194/7224) : la phrase réelle est « J'ai mangé les pommes. » On a simplement déplacé le complément par un artifice, mais la grammaire demeure inchangée.

Danielle Leeman note quelques cas où l'accord se fait, mais toujours avec des temps composés :

> a. *Trois enfants, j'ai eus* (Wagner et Pinchon)
>   b. *Ma chemise, j'aurais donnée pour en être* (Grevisse)
>   c. *Bien des ennuis, il avait eus* (Grevisse)

L'article Wikipédia donne un exemple tiré de Ronsard déplaçant le complément avant le participe passé mais ne suscitant pas d'accord pour autant :

> Las ! voyez comme en peu d'espace,
>   Mignonne, elle a dessus la place
>   Las ! Las ! ses beautés laissé choir

Danielle Leeman donne d'autres exemples avec ou sans reprise pronominale :

> a. *La faim, t'as pas connu/tu l'as pas connue*
>   b. *Sa réaction, j'ai pas compris/je l'ai pas comprise*

Pour moi (et [cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/linversion-et-laccord-du-participe-pass%C3%A9/14193#comment26854_14193)), ces exemples sont très clairement tirés du français parlé et il est difficile d'en extraire une règle d'orthographe.

### Ce que l'on pourrait en conclure

La règle générale (ou en tout cas un moyen mnémotechnique) semble donc être :

> Le participe passé avec l'auxiliaire *avoir* s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec le complément d'objet direct :
>
> - (cas de la tournure affirmative) lorsque celui-ci est repris sous forme pronominale avant le verbe ;
> - (cas de la tournure interrogative) lorsque celui-ci est situé avant le verbe.

Quelques exemples :

> J'ai pris les pommes.
>   Les pommes, j'ai pris.
>   Les pommes **que** j'ai pris**es**.
>   Les pommes, je **les** ai pris**es**.
>
> ---
>
> Le fermier a lavé quelles brebis ?
>   **Quelles brebis** le fermier a-t-il lavé**es** ?

<sub>[L'utilisation du PP « pris »](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14204/7224) permet de se rendre compte à l'oral de la présence d'accord au féminin ou non.</sub>
<sub>Comment les scripts de Yoda accordés doivent être, maintenant on sait.</sub>

---

<sub>**Références :**

- [Forums de *leconjugueur*](http://forum.leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/viewtopic.php?id=769)

- Hyperbate : [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbate) et [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperbate)

- [*Les aventures de Max et Eve, j’ai aimé : à propos d’un COD « Canada Dry »*, Danielle Leeman, Hommages à Maurice Gross, Philadelphie/Amsterdam, Benjamins (pp. 405-412)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_v8CHB7yvW0C&lpg=PR2&ots=MCHUZtauSu&dq=Lexique%2C%20syntaxe%20et%20lexique-grammaire%20%20publi%C3%A9%20par%20Christian%20Lecl%C3%A8re%2CMaurice&hl=fr&pg=PA405#v=onepage&q&f=true)</sub>

Comment: Lien très intéressant. Une impression diffuse que ces tournures sont orales ou sont  des transcriptions de dialogues, ou encore du domaine de l'évocation poétique. Sorties de leur contexte, elles 'heurtent' la prosodie scriptée.

Comment: La référence citée (Leeman 2004) semble défendre la position inverse de celle exprimée ici. Danièle Leeman soutient que dans cette construction, les pommes n'est pas COD de manger...

Comment: @GAMPUB J'avoue avoir par moment un peu de mal à suivre son discours, mais « Le groupe antéposé _la tarte_ en (1) paraît donc bien être le [COD] du verbe _aimer_ » (p. 406). Elle définit la structure comme une « topicalisation, définie comme le **déplacement frontal d'un complément régi** sans reprise pronominale ». **Mais** j'ai fait une erreur en voulant lire trop vite : cela ne conduit pas à l'accord : « l'absence d'accord du participe passé serait à imputer au déplacement frontal ou à un illogisme dans l'orthographe du français. » Je vais modifier un peu ma réponse.

Comment: @Archa J'ai réécrit la réponse suite aux remarques de GAM PUB et ma relecture de la source. Je te laisse relire et voir si tu veux la conserver comme réponse acceptée ou non (pour résumer, j'ai lu trop vite et il n'y a en fait pas d'accord).

Comment: @cl-r L'utilisation d'exemples permettant la perception de l'accord serait bienvenue pour éviter le problème des jugements de valeur sur écrit vs oral. Il existe de l'écrit informel et de  l'oral formel, dans tous les cas, l'utilisation d'exemples avec une différence audible entre les formes discutées permet de se faire une meilleure idée de la règle.

Comment: @GAMPUB Merci, j'ai pris exemple sur ta réponse.

Comment: @GAMPUB Ce n'est pas du tout un jugement de valeur issu d'un savoir que je n'ai en aucune façon, ni un parti pris pour avoir raison ou afficher un point de vue, mais quelque chose de ressenti : j'ai en mémoire ces tournures dans la sphère de l'oralité, du spontané, de la réaction à une situation (même si elle peuvent être transcrites pour créer cet atmosphère) ; la construction scriptée éditée pour être lue silencieusement semble peu encline à utiliser ces raccourcis dans son projet de transmission.

Comment: @cl-r Mon point concernait précisément le fait que les données discutées n'appartenaient pas aux contextes où l'intuition peut jouer un rôle dans la mesure où rien n'était audible. Dans la lecture silencieuse, certaines constructions impossibles surgissent parfois, par exemple avec l'accord des adjectifs épithètes portant sur deux noms : Des romans et des histoires intéressants (peu vraisemblable en dehors de la lecture silencieuse).

Comment: @GAMPUB Ce n'est pas l'accord qui me préoccupe, mais la suppression d'un (plusieurs) mot(s) : "les pommes, je *les* ai mangé" est la phrase qui est normalement attendue en français, alors que "les pommes j'ai mangé" peut être entendu dans la bouche d'un enfant, qui ne sait pas (ou à peine) écrire et ne connaît pas toutes les règles et usages qui surchargent son expression intuitive.

Comment: @chop, l'exemple tiré de Ronsard est différent: je pense qu'il n'y a pas accord à cause de la présence d'une proposition infinitive (choir) après le participe. Mais , bon, ce n'est qu'un point de détail.

Comment: @user45784 Tout à fait juste, merci. :) L'académie française a écrit  : « **[...] l'application de cette règle étant parfois malaisée, particulièrement dans les formes pronominales, et l'accord restant incertain dans l'usage, on pourra, comme pour le verbe _faire_, généraliser l'invariabilité du participe passé de _laisser_ dans le cas où il est suivi d'un infinitif. Il est donc possible d'écrire : _Elle s'est laissé mourir_ comme _Elle s'est fait maigrir_ ; _Je les ai laissé partir_ comme _Je les ai fait partir_.** »

Comment: Est-ce que l'accord se fait même avec réelle inversion du sujet avec avoir ?
"Dans le silence, ont été aperçues des ombres qui terrorisaient les accords des participes passés !" oui
mais
"Les dates d'examen qu'ont programmé(es?) les professeurs..."

Answer (score 2):

Ta phrase "Les pommes j'ai mangé." n'est pas grammaticalement tout à fait correcte. Pour qu'elle le soit, il faut y mettre une virgule:

"Les pommes, j'ai mangé", on a ainsi une apposition qui nous permet de modifier l'ordre normal des mots de la phrase.

Comme c'est simplement l'ordre qui est changé, le "j'ai mangé" est absolument le même que dans "J'ai mangé les pommes", il n'y a pas à faire un accord, car le "ai mangé" est un verbe, et pas du tout un adjectif.

J'ai mangé les pommes.

Les pommes sont mangées. Les pommes mangées.

Dans ces deux phrase, la nature de "mangé" est complètement différente. Un verbe dans la première, et un adjectif à la deuxième ligne.

Comment: C'est exactement ce que j'ai pensé en premier lieu, mais j'ai quand même cherché par acquis de conscience. Une référence ne fait pas tout et je serai curieux d'en voir d'autres si tu en as à proposer (j'aimerais bien pouvoir dire que mon instinct était bon).

Comment: Je suis entrain de l'article de Wikipédia sur l'accord du participe passé en français et je suis tombé sur cette phrase interrogative : « Quelles brebis le fermier a-t-il lavées ? » Je vais vous aider pour le lien: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord_du_participe_pass%C3%A9_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Accord_entre_objet_et_qualificatif_conjugu.C3.A9

Comment: Je peux me tromper. J'avoue que quand j'ai vu ton explication, j'ai été prise d'un doute. J'aimerais voir si la phrase pourrait être transposée avec d'autres mots, pour voir si on retrouve la même construction grammaticale. Est-ce une simple inversion du sujet, ou est-ce que ça nécessite un accord? Je pense qu'on aura plus d'infos si on arrive à transposer avec d'autres mots.

Comment: @Archa On n'est plus du tout dans le même cas de figure. Dans ta phrase, tu as une inversion car c'est une question, elle ne pose aucune difficulté quant à l'accord.

Comment: Ok.

Je me demande, si ça marche pour les pronoms relatifs, pourquoi pas pour les groupes nominaux?

Comment: Quand je remplace avec un démonstratif: Ces bonbons, il les a aimés! Il y a bien accord. Il faudrait que j'édite ma réponse pour rajouter cela. Avec le démonstratif, je trouve qu'il n'y a plus aucun doute à avoir, il y a bien accord. Et si j'enlève le démonstratif pour revenir à ma phrase: Les bonbons, j'ai mangés. J'ai tort, et Chop a raison, tout est plus clair quand on substitue par d'autres mots. Je pense que la règle fait référence à la place du COD par rapport au verbe, c'est ça qui semble être l'unique critère.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Ton exemple avec le démonstratif n'est pas le même : ton accord ne se fait pas avec « Ces bonbons », mais avec « les » : le COD est ici le pronom avant le verbe (même si à la fin, « les » désigne « ces bonbons ») : « _Ces bonbons_, il **les** a aimés. » Je ne sais pas si cela fonctionne vraiment pour justifier ce que j'ai trouvé.

Answer (score 1):

Une remarque s’impose dans la réponse  qui a été donnée  plus haut :

« Ce que l'on pourrait en conclure
La règle générale (ou en tout cas un moyen mnémotechnique) semble donc être :
Le participe passé avec l'auxiliaire avoir s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec le complément d'objet direct :
(cas de la tournure affirmative) lorsque celui-ci est repris sous forme pronominale avant le verbe ;
(cas de la tournure interrogative) lorsque celui-ci est situé avant le verbe.
Quelques exemples :

J'ai pris les pommes.
Les pommes, j'ai pris.
Les pommes que j'ai prises.
Les pommes, je les ai prises.

Le fermier a lavé quelles brebis ?
Quelles brebis le fermier a-t-il lavées ? »

—- Pour le cas de la tournure interrogative, un mot interrogatif est indispensable pour que la règle ( l’accord du PP)  s'applique.
Ainsi, « Quelles brebis le fermier a-t-il lavées ? » avec l’adjectif interrogatif quel(le)(s).
L’accord ne se fait pas dans une phrase interrogative sans mot interrogatif. Pour reprendre les exemples avancés :
Les pommes, tu as pris ? 
( différent de : Les pommes, tu les as prises ? 
Et bien sûr différent de : Quelles pommes tu as prises ?)
Avec un autre mot interrogatif (pronom lequel/laquelle) :
Lesquelles de ces pommes as-tu prises ?

Answer (score 0):

Il semble que les phrases suivantes partagent le même type de structure où le COD est coréférent avec les pommes :

1. avec accord

   - Les pommes, j'ai mangées dans le jardin.
   - Les pommes, j'ai prises dans le jardin.
2. sans accord

   - Les pommes, j'ai mangé dans le jardin.
   - Les pommes, j'ai pris dans le jardin.

L'accord serait audible sur prendre s'il était réalisé. Il semble que peu de francophones produirait cette phrase avec l'accord au féminin...